# Java method to accept mixed number fraction and return a double

Tags: java, methods, fractions

I need help getting this method to accept a mixed number e.g. (2 1/2) stored as one variable instead of two. Currently I have int and frac which come from two separate text fields.

```
public double convertFrac(int whole, String frac){
        if (frac == null || frac.equals(""))
            return whole;
        String[] parts = frac.split("/");
        return whole + (double)Integer.parseInt(parts[0]) / (double)Integer.parseInt(parts[1]);
    }
```

edited the code thanks to a suggestion from Bohemian.

it may be clunky by some of your standards, but I got it working =D

```
public static double convertFrac(String frac){
        String wholeStr, num, denom, fraction;
        int whole = 0;
        String[] parts = frac.split(" ");
        wholeStr = parts[0];
        whole = Integer.parseInt(wholeStr);

        if(parts.length == 1){
            return whole;
        }

        wholeStr = parts[0];
        whole = Integer.parseInt(parts[0]);
        fraction = parts[1];
        String[] fracParts = fraction.split("/");
        num = fracParts[0];
        denom = fracParts[1];

        return whole + (double)Integer.parseInt(fracParts[0]) / (double)Integer.parseInt(fracParts[1]);
    }
```

Comment: Please provide some sample input, actual output and expected output.  the code for `fracToDec` might be helpful.

Comment: The user would input a whole number (21) and then a fraction in the form of a String (5/8). Tokenizer and parse int is used to create two integers "num" and "denom". Those variable are passed to a method fracToDec() where they are converted to a decimal. That decimal is then added to the whole number.

Comment: @Steve I added the method you requested above.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is bug #1:

```
if(frac == ""){ // tests if frac is the same object as the blank constant
```

You must use

```
if(frac.equals("")){ // tests if fraq is blank
```

This is bug #2:

```
num = Integer.parseInt(frac); // will explode if frac is actually a fraction
```

---

Instead of what you have, I would simplify it to this:

```
public double convertFrac(int whole, String frac) {
    if (frac == null || frac.equals(""))
        return whole;
    String[] parts = frac.split("/");
    return whole + (double)Integer.parseInt(parts[0]) / (double)Integer.parseInt(parts[1]);
}
```

You should not consider `frac` having only one number, because it makes no sense. Either it's blank or it's a fraction.

Comment: Integer division.. convert to double before dividing

Comment: @Bohemian that looks good! My only concern is that my main issue was for the method to take the fraction as one. So instead of passing whole and frac. I could pass only one variable. Does this make sense?

Comment: if it helps. Both whole and frac are taken from two separate textFields. This is what I don't want. I would like to have only one textField.

Comment: @billabrian6 - if you have those values from user inputs - it is generally a good idea to verify format better, because users will enter something what you cannot even expect :)

Comment: The program is actually for personal use. I just want to be able to enter 21 1/8 instead 21 then 1/8